# Handle exception and halt execution

Tags: java, codenameone

In my current Codename One GUI builder application I set the command action of a `Button` to open a new form.

**Current Behaviour** - when there's no connection, it shows the error message and then goes to the next form.

**Required Behaviour** - I want to halt the execution and stay in the current form if there is any exception occurred.

How can i achieve that ?

```
@Override
protected void handleErrorResponseCode(int code, String message) {
    Dialog.show("Error msg", "The server returned the error code: " + code, "ok", null);
}
```

Comment: Where are you calling your next form? Kindly post complete code for your connectionRequest?

Comment: i hav a btn in the main form that i set the action command to NextForm. In beforeNextForm{
    connectionRequest code...
}

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest avoiding a command and instead just invoking:

```
showForm("DestinationForm", null);
```

In the `postResponse` method of the connection request when you have made a successful request.

Alternatively you can press the go to code button in the command editing dialog, this method allows you to return a boolean value indicating whether navigation should proceed.

Comment: thanks shai, it works when kept in postResponse... BTW i didnt get ur alternative way. where is "go to code btn in the command editing dialog"??

Comment: In the gui builder click on the command entry in the properties which will open a large dialog. In it there is a "go to code" option. That will bring you to a method where you can return true/false to navigate or not and implement your logic there. I don't recommend that method.